# iPhone - press button open URL?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, button, ios4

1) user launch application
2) user press button
3) button loads http://domain.com/mypage/?item=123

How do you trigger http://domain.com/?item=123, without opening the actual page in the browser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[NSURLConnection](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html) is the answer.

Comment: ASIHTTPRequest is the better answer.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure of what the question is, but you could use a `UIWebView`. Load that `UIWebView` in the app with the URL and you should be good to go.

Hope this helps!

Comment: dont want to open the URL for the user to view, want to trigger the URL, (load in background ie  when the URL is triggered, that page activates a piece of hardware).

Comment: UIWebView is a very heavy object for what may be a simple HTTP request

Comment: @Wayne: Yup, totally agreed, based on what 001 is asking. Wasn't entirely sure what he/she was asking..

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString* str = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://domain.com/?item=123"] usedEncoding:NULL error:NULL]
```

Comment: Not only is it spelled NSURL, this call is synchronous and will block the current thread.

Answer (score -1):

I have used  a UIWebView set to "hidden".  It probably is not the most efficient way but if you normally use UIWebViews and Interface Builder then it is easy.  You can also use the webview delegate methods to watch it.

On second thought - use the NSURL String method above but put it in a new thread.

Comment: Terrible approach.  The UIWebView is an extremely heavy object that should not be used with impunity.